# Implementing ASP.NET MVC Ajax.ActionLink with Image

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to implement the Ajax helper as per the previous question at [ASP.NET MVC Ajax.ActionLink with Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341649/asp-net-mvc-ajax-actionlink-with-image)

Using Asp.net MVC 3

When I try to add the class the line return link.Replace("[rep.... gives and error for the "link.replace" code, saying "System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' does not contain a definition for 'Replace' "

Can anyone advise on this? I also get the same error if I download the referenced project

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert it to a regular string and back again :

```
return new MvcHtmlString(link.ToString().Replace("[replaceme]", builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing)));
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't quite understand you comment, can you show me the full text to replace?

Comment: Thanks Adam, I've tried that but I get an error for the MvcString part. Which assembly is that in?

Comment: woops! it was MvcHtmlString (teaches me to do from my phone haha)

Answer (score 1):

You might find this helpful. It allows styling and other options:

```
public static class ImageHelpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// return image link
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="helper"></param>
    /// <param name="id">Id of link control</param>
    /// <param name="controller">target controller name</param>
    /// <param name="action">target action name</param>
    /// <param name="strOthers">other URL parts like query string, etc</param>
    /// <param name="strImageURL">URL for image</param>
    /// <param name="alternateText">Alternate Text for the image</param>
    /// <param name="strStyle">style of the image like border properties, etc</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ImageLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string controller, string action, string strOthers, string strImageURL, 
        string alternateText, string strStyle, string cssClass = "imagelink")
    {
        return ImageLink(helper, id, controller, action, strOthers, strImageURL, alternateText, strStyle, null, cssClass);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// return image link
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="helper"></param>
    /// <param name="id">Id of link control</param>
    /// <param name="controller">target controller name</param>
    /// <param name="action">target action name</param>
    /// <param name="strOthers">other URL parts like query string, etc</param>
    /// <param name="strImageURL">URL for image</param>
    /// <param name="alternateText">Alternate Text for the image</param>
    /// <param name="strStyle">style of the image like border properties, etc</param>
    /// <param name="htmlAttributes">html attributes for link</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ImageLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string controller, string action, string strOthers, string strImageURL,
        string alternateText, string strStyle, object htmlAttributes, string cssClass = "imagelink")
    {
        var portalModel = ContextCache<PortalModel>.Get(ContextCache.PortalModelSessionCache);

        // Create tag builder
        var divBuilder = new TagBuilder("div");
        divBuilder.AddCssClass(cssClass);

        var aBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");

        // Create valid id
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            aBuilder.GenerateId(id);

        // Add attributes
        aBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", "/" + portalModel.PortalTag + "/" + controller + "/" + action + strOthers); //form target URL
        aBuilder.InnerHtml = "<img src='" + strImageURL + "' alt='" + alternateText + "' class='" + cssClass + "' style='border: none;'/>" + alternateText; //set the image as inner html
        aBuilder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

        divBuilder.InnerHtml = aBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal); //to add </a> as end tag

        // Render tag
        return divBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  but that appears to be for HtmlHelper? Is there a version to use with AjaxHelper?