# MVC: Is that possible to Ajax.ActionLink with an image and the text on the right hand side with the image?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, actionlink

I have created the following button based on Ajax.ActionLink logic:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("View Details", "Method", "Controller",
new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "showProgress", OnComplete = "showImage", OnFailure = "ReportError" },
new { @class = "modal-link k-button btn-icon-sm btn-view-detail k-icon k-i-file-txt", style = "width: 150px; height:70px;" })
```

That produces the following image with the Action Description and Action Image underneath:

[image]

This is the `html` that represents the button:

```
<a title="View Details" class="modal-link k-button btn-icon-sm btn-view-detail k-icon k-i-file-txt" style="width: 150px; height: 100px;" href="/Controller/GetData?Length=9" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-container" data-ajax-failure="CheckError" data-ajax-complete="showLoaderPopup" data-ajax-begin="showLoader" data-ajax="true">View Details</a>
```

How can I modify it, so I the button will have Action Image followed by Action Description on the right hand side of the image. It has to be one button>

Is there any template for Ajax.ActionLink that I can use to display what I need?

Comment: Sounds like this is a CSS selector arrangement issue. Can you provide which class that contains image (and text) definition? Try `float:left` for image and `overflow:hidden` for text.

Comment: I added `html` code that represents the button

Comment: try to increase the width it may help, it will be better to share your css of used css classes.