# ASP.NET MVC Ajax.ActionLink with Image bind to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have been trying to make this work and I can't figure out what is wrong with this code. The ajax works great, but I can't display the image.

```
@Html.Raw(@Ajax.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "_ProductDetail", new
{
  productID = item.ProductsID

},
new AjaxOptions
{
 HttpMethod = "POST",
 UpdateTargetId = "detail",
 LoadingElementId = "loading",
 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
 })
 .ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]","<img src=\"~/images/tn/@item.Ptn)\" />"))
```

I also tried `<img src=\"~/images/tn/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.Ptn)`

If I put the hard coded image name, it works fine.

Any ideas? I read some other answers here using helpers but I could not make it work either.

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: Just the default missing image in a browser. the problem is with the path of the image , where if I click fires the ajax link,

Comment: No, I mean if you right click -> View Source, what is the HTML?

Comment: <img src="~/images/tn/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =&gt;item.Ptn)">

Comment: or <img src="~/images/tn/@item.Ptn">

Comment: Thats what shows up in your browser?

Comment: yes only that. it is not rendering the item.Ptn, on the other hand I can get that item.Ptn by itself outside of that

Comment: the whole thing is this

Comment: <img src="~/images/tn/@item.Ptn">
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-loading="#loading" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#detail" href="/Product/_ProductDetail?productID=1453"><img src="~/images/tn/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =&gt;item.Ptn)"></a>

Comment: Well my first guess is that if you are seeing the `@` character in rendered HTML then you are somehow escaping that character in your razor syntax.  MVC razor will run on the server to generate HTML.  You will never see Razor syntax in your rendered HTML.

Comment: I know but I do not know how to concatenate the string to separate the razor syntax for the rest so razor will do the render

Comment: Do you want the result to be an anchor (`<a>`) tag with an image inside it?

Comment: I just need a image be the link to the controller with ajax.actionlink, what ever it is I do not care. if is <a> is fine

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341649/asp-net-mvc-ajax-actionlink-with-image) SO answer

Comment: looking into all solutions there. thank, I will let you know