# Wanting to use an image with text in Html.ActionLink

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the following:

```
<img src="../../Content/Images/lock_16.gif" />
@Html.ActionLink("Register", 
   "Register", 
   "Users", 
   null, 
   new { title = "Register your ID", rel = "nofollow" 
})
```

What I would like is for the lock image to appear inside of the `<a> </a>` so it is clickable and not before it. I already use (and change color on hover) of a background image so its not possible for me to use the background-image property to display the image.

Can anyone think of a way that I can set the image so that it will show before the text and still be clickable. Hopefully I can find a way that still allows me to use the MVC Html.ActionLink.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question. What do you mean by "appear inside"? Do you mean you want both the image and text to be clickable?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Yes I would like the image and text to appear inside the <a> </a> and both be clickable.

Comment: duplicate of [Image equivalent of ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210711/image-equivalent-of-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Html helpers in ASP.NET MVC should be used when they simplify writing code, not always. Plain html would go way better in your case

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Register", "Users")" title="Register Your ID", rel="nofollow">
     Register <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/lock_16.gif")" />
</a>
```

Note that link address is still generated dynamically, using `UrlHelper.Action` method. This way, you do not lose link dependency to your route configuration. Also, as Nicholas mentioned, image source should be generated via `Url.Content` helper.

Comment: You should also use <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/lock_16.gif") />

Comment: I think ur ans is better than Mark's ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596444/html-actionlink-as-a-button-or-an-image-not-a-link

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like -

```
@Html.ActionLink("link Name", "Action Method", "Controller", new { style = "background-image:url('.././Images/imageName.png')" },null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink("link Name", "Action Method", "Controller", 
   new { style = "background-image:url('.././Images/imageName.png')" },
   null)
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.